# Object doesn't support property or method 'MaterialSelect'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Material Select Initialization
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mdb-select").materialSelect();
    });
</script>
```

```html
<select class="mdb-select md-form" multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
        <option value="1">USA</option>
        <option value="2">Germany</option>
        <option value="3">France</option>
        <option value="3">Poland</option>
        <option value="3">Japan</option>
    </select>
    <label>Label exampenter code hereenter code herele</label>
    <button`enter code here` class="btn-save btn btn-danger btn-sm">Save</button>
```

I am getting error : Object doesn't support property or method 'MaterialSelect' I have used bootstrap and the link to the source is : https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: The `materialize.js` library you've put in the script reference is something completely different to the Bootstrap multiselect library you linked to in the question. You need to reference the correct library

Comment: From their documentation, these are the correct links: https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to use CDNs of materializecss instead of mdbootstrap. Try CDNs from here https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/

Comment: tried that but getting the same error @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

the error what you are facing is indicating that there is no method or property of name 'MaterialSelect' which you are trying to access.

To make MaterialSelect method available you have to include correct CDNs of the library which you are trying to use. People have already mentioned the solution in the comments.

If you having trouble understanding the error. Please reach out to me.

Cheers :)

Comment: I understood them but I am not getting which library to use and I tried them but getting the same error

Comment: the library what you have added in your code is not from material design bootstrap. It is from MaterializeCSS - https://materializecss.com/

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

You have to take correct CDN for material design bootstrap and use it.

let me know if you are having trouble getting the correct one. Cheers :)

Comment: i am not getting that library need help